# popup menu items click listener function not working

Tags: android, xml, popup, android-menu

I have a popup menu and I'm implementing the actions for the items inside the menu; however, when pressing second item in menu "notification" nothing happens. the first item works "change icon" but not the second. I'm suspecting a problem with evenlistener inside the function. if someone can point me to proper way of doing this. I was check android dev documentation and they implement a bit different. 
main activity

```
package org.pctechtips.menulistview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList hosts;
    String ipAdd = "192.168.10.";
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    PopupMenu popup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            hosts.add(ipAdd+i);
        }

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.ip_address, hosts);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        //registering the menu with the listview
//        registerForContextMenu(list);

    }

    /* code for popup menu in listview */
    public void showPopupMenu(View v) {
        popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, popup.getMenu());

        /* handling event listeners*/
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.change_icon:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.notifications:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return MainActivity.super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
                }
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }

}
```

popup menu xml file

```
 <!-- listview menu for host scan options eg:
         change hostname, icon, notification etc -->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/change_icon"
        android:title="change icon"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>


    <itme android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:title="notifications"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/set_hostname"
        android:title="set notification"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You are getting the same title so you will not notice the chance..

Comment: why am I getting same title.. I using getItemId() method to identify the id of the item clicked. Unless, I'm not understanding how the method works. menuItem.getTtitle() reflects the title of the item being clicked or not?

Comment: anybody know how to respond to clicks events from a popup menu?

Comment: using log.v("menuId", menuItem.getItemId()+" "+R.id.change_icon+" "+R.id.notifications); I'm getting same id for change_icon but different for notifications why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `item` misspelled in your menu file for notifications.

```
<itme android:id="@+id/notifications"
    android:title="notifications"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Could that be the issue?

---

Just tested and that seems to be the issue. Correct the spelling and the menu should work OK.

Comment: yes.. that is exactly the problem.. I guess the debugger can't catch it